VirtualBox: Kali Linux guest VM dual monitor issues
The following question serves to ask for any possible solutions, and to also share the workarounds I have found
I have a host machine running Ubuntu 24.04.4 LTS with dual monitor. I have booted up Kali Linux on VirtualBox according to the tutorial: https://www.kali.org/docs/virtualization/install-virtualbox-guest-vm/. Everything works well with a single screen for the guest Kali Linux VM, but seems to be unstable for dual screens.
I enabled dual monitor screen for my guest Kali to take up dual screens with the following steps:

Settings -> Display -> Monitor count (slide to 2)
Within the guest VM: View -> Virtual Screen 2 -> Enable

However, the following issues came up on the guest Kali VM:

The display starts flickering and gets distorted when the window is resized manually using the mouse


Is this behavior normal?

Current workarounds found for screen flickering issue

The display seems to be more stable when the resize button (square icon) on the top right corner of the window is used instead

Top menu bar: View -> Virtual Screen 1/2 -> Resize to <value>...



These two methods seems to reduce the screen flickering occurences, but doesn't completely fix it.

Morever in full-screen mode (hostkey + F):

Mouse pointer events and interactions were not working - icons not being able to be clicked. The mouse is still visible and is able to be pan between both screens still.

Fix for full-screen mode mouse click issue

Settings (hostkey + S from guest VM) -> User Interface -> Unselect/disable the Mini toolbar: Show in Full-Screen/Seamless option


Note: The screen flickering issue seems to not really be an issue in full-screen mode

Have anyone encountered this issue, and found any other workarounds or solutions?
